# Raspberry Pi Camera Module v3 with legacy camera stack

Tags: camera, opencv

Can Raspberry Pi Camera Module v3 load with legacy camera stack? I tried but no luck.

Is OpenCV only support camera that loaded with legacy camera stack? Anyone success to load Raspberry Pi Camera Module v3 with OpenCV

I know that Picamera2 will works with Raspberry Pi Camera Module v3 but I wish to use OpenCV library instead of Picamera2.